# unable to declare time object in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I'm a bit new to this and I'm working with datetime data in python. Two questions:

I have a time column that is associated with events, but I'm having difficulty declaring it as time using datetime.time. I have a time column that is formatted like this:

```
0       11:17:43
1       06:00:00
2       06:30:35
3       02:00:00
4       23:00:00
5       13:20:49
6       19:30:00
```

and am attempting to declare it as a time object

```
data['timeobject'] = datetime.time(data['start_time'], axis = 1)
```

But am getting this error message:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'

Also, I'd like to take this time object and use as a dependent variable using scikit-learn classification or regression.

How do I declare it a time object, and would there be any issues running it through scikit-learn models to predict when an event might happen?

Thank you!

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `scikit-learn` (the "also" part is a completely different question altogether, and arguably too broad) - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), and not the standard library `datetime`

```
data['timeobject'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_time'], format='%h:%m:%s')
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.time` does not work in a vectorised fashion. Pandas top-level [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#to-timedelta) does, and it accepts a wide range of formats, including strings in the format you have supplied. Given a dataframe with column `'td'`:

```
df['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['td'])

print(df)

0   11:17:43
1   06:00:00
2   06:30:35
3   02:00:00
4   23:00:00
5   13:20:49
6   19:30:00
Name: td, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Underlying the resultant series is an integer array via `np.timedelta64`. You should expect this to work well with the scikit-learn framework.